# Where are the possible places to define propertie references in Java Spring projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im currently trying to understand some legacy Java Spring MVC code and having a hard time finding where are the properties references in the code are located. There are two types of reference annotations I run into:

```
1: ${aaa.bbb.ccc}

2: ddd.eee=http://@URL@/link
   fff.ggg=@PORT@
```

Now my questions are what is the difference between the two ways of referencing properties and where can I find the origin of the properites?

Update:
So the `${aaa.bbb.ccc}` is how to specify properties in Spring according to the answeres. Now the secound part of my question is where does `@PORT@` come from. This reference can be found inside the `*.properties` files

Answer (score 0):

Search for files ending in *.properties !

If you have in context somethong like :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file.properties"/>
```

You can have a spring bean with properties

```
<bean id="myProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="myProperties">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:file.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Also check this [link http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/)

Comment: Use CTRL+SHIT+R in Eclipse for searching

Comment: Yes but the @...@ can not be found anywhere. Im starting to suspect that this is something i specify using maven CLI?

Comment: if you have fff.ggg=@PORT@ in a properties file is just a key-value pair. Can you pot the usage of fff.ggg to see how is handled ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `@...@` is a maven filtering, because default delimiters for spring properties and maven are the same `${...}` they changed maven delimiters with `@...@` (override resource delimiter).

> File filtering is used to substitute variable fields from inside a
>   file to their represented values. For the Assembly Plugin, and most
>   Maven filtering procedures, these variables are enclosed between ${
>   and }. For example, before a file is filtered, it contains
>   ${project.artifactId}. But after filtering is complete, a new file is
>   created with the project's artifactId substituting
>   ${project.artifactId} and that this new file is used instead of the
>   original one.

source: 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

Or it can be an replacement made in Ant

```
<replace 
    file="configure.sh"
    value="defaultvalue"
    propertyFile="src/name.properties">
  <replacefilter 
    token="@token1@"/>
  <replacefilter 
    token="@token2@" 
    value="value2"/>
  <replacefilter 
    token="@token3@" 
    property="property.key"/>
  <replacefilter>
    <replacetoken>@token4@</replacetoken> 
    <replacevalue>value4</replacevalue>
  </replacefilter>
</replace>
```

> In file configure.sh, replace all instances of "@token1@" with
>   "defaultvalue", all instances of "@token2@" with "value2", and all
>   instances of "@token3@" with the value of the property "property.key",
>   as it appears in property file src/name.properties.

source:https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html